# How to attach a file from an url with django weasyprint?

Tags: python, django, weasyprint

I'm trying to attach a file from an url with django and weasyprint, django-weasyprint

The pdf view:

```
class OrdineDetailView(LoginRequiredMixin, DetailView):
    model = Ordine

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context["merce"] = OrdineMerce.objects.filter(ordine=kwargs.get("object"))
        return context


class OrdinePrintView(WeasyTemplateResponseMixin, OrdineDetailView):
    # output of MyDetailView rendered as PDF with hardcoded CSS
    pdf_stylesheets = [
        settings.STATIC_ROOT / "ordini/ordine.css",
    ]
    # show pdf in-line (default: True, show download dialog)
    pdf_attachment = True
```

Then I have an api endpoint that when hit it sends an email.

```
class InviaOrdineView(APIView):
    def get(self, request, pk):
        pdf_url = f"{settings.PROTOCOL}gestione.{settings.PARENT_HOST}/ordini/{pk}/pdf/"

        url = urllib.request.urlopen(pdf_url)
        pdf = url.read()

        mail = EmailMessage(
            "Ordine merce",
            "Con questa vi ordiniamo la merce che trovate in allegato a questa email.",
            settings.DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL,
            [settings.DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL, email_fornitore],
        )
        mail.attach("ordine.pdf", pdf, "application/pdf")

        mail.send()
```

The email is sent but the attachment cannot be read.

How to attach a file via url?

Comment: What does the attachment in the resulting email look like? Is it completely missing, or present but corrupt? Is there a reason you need to fetch the pdf as a web request, and can't call the PDF-generating class directly?

Comment: @match the file is present and corrupted

Comment: My guess is that `url.read()` is returning a bytes object when `attach()` is expecting a string. You could try `pdf = url.read().decode('utf-8')` (or whatever encoding it is returned as) as a quick check.

Comment: @match unluckly it doesn't work

Comment: Can you write `pdf` to a file and check that it is a valid pdf file?